# SwipeRefreshLayout with scrollView and Layout above

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I have the following layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            //some views here
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The problem is when I scrolldown the table, I can't scrollUp again because the swipelayout is being triggered. How can I trigger the swiperefresh only when the first view of the table is visible?

Comment: Please post the full xml for this layout and the other_layout, as I don't see your `SwipeRefreshLayout`... for reference, `SwipeRefreshLayout` can only have 1 child view.

Comment: I editted my question. Sorry for the misleading information!

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I found that if you replace your `ScrollView` with a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` the scrolling behavior will work as you expect it to.

Comment: My problem is a little bit different. No matter where on the screen whenever i swipe down, the SwipeRefreshLayout pickup the motion , making it unable to scroll the view down, unless it's in refreshing state. Or I must swipe up first then swipe down without remove the finger. Your solution helped alot. Thanks.

Comment: In case if you have migrated to androidX, use `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 10):

Make your own implementation of SwipeRefreshLayout and override the canChildScrollUp in this way:

```
    @Override
public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
    if (scrollView != null)
        return scrollView.canScrollVertically(-1);

    return false;
}
```

just replace with any subclass of ScrollView.

Comment: where to implement this method

Comment: extend the SwipeRefreshLayout and put the above code

Comment: It's not necessary to implement a custom `SwipeRefreshLayout`. We can just add `setOnChildScrollUpCallback()` on `SwipeRefreshLayout` and put our logic inside the callback.

Answer (score 7):

If you have layout like this:

```xml
<SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/your_scroll_view_id">
        <LinearLayout>
        ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

You need to create your own class and override the function in this way:

```java
class SwipeRefreshLayoutCustom extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
    public SwipeRefreshLayoutCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes)
    }
    @override
    boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        return your_scroll_view_id.scrollY != 0
    }
}
```

Comment: If the LinearLayout Contains a bunch of other views with a RecyclerView, then the RecyclerView will actually behave like a list view, all viewholders biind method will be called at once.

Answer (score -4):

Use NestedScrollView with:

```
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```