# Layout not moving when its inside to SwipeRefreshLayout in android?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I working with SwipeRefreshLayout. Here what my need is...
Im using one Linearlayout inside SwipeRefreshLayout which is in "**RED COLOR**".
when im trying to pull down that layout, that layout is not moving. Only its showing that refresh circular arrow, But i want to pull down that whole "**Red color**" layout. How to achieve this?

Please find my sources for reference.

Suggestion please....

**mylayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000">


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample SwipeRefreshLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,null);


    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView);
    onCreateSwipeToRefresh(swipeLayout);


    return  view;
}

private void onCreateSwipeToRefresh(SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout) {

    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(android.R.color.holo_green_dark,  android.R.color.holo_red_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_blue_dark,   android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);

}


@Override
public void onRefresh() {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead for using a `ScrollView` as child of `SwipeRefreshLayout`, try using a `RelativeLayout` / `LinearLayout` and make the ScrollView a child of it.

something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    >
   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000">
       <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            
            //Leave the interior the same

       </ScrollView>
   </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Also apply the red color to your `LinearLayout`. You currently have it in your `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Comment: but still that red color whole layout is not moving :(

Comment: any other solutions or ideas?

Comment: Please note that i've edited my answer. I removed the background definition from the SwipeRefreshLayout, and added it into the LinearLayout., it worked for me. Please also check this answer - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294395/swiperefreshlayout-with-scrollview-and-layout-above?rq=1 (I belive your ScrollView might be the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ScrollView` should not `wrap_content` on its height but `match_parent`

Comment: i've followed your suggestion..but still can't able to move that layout.
any other solutions or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Used `PullRefreshLayout` instead `SwipeRefreshLayout` [from this sample](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/android-PullRefreshLayout)